# Скрывающийся при прокрутке ActionBar (ToolBar)

Tags: java, android

Недавно я задался вопросом, как реализована анимация в мобильном приложении Twitter.

При прокручивании ленты вверх, нижняя панель, предназначенная для ввода твита, очень плавно уходит вниз. Если при движении вверх остановиться на том моменте когда панель ушла только на половину и убрать палец, она автоматически скроется.
При прокручивании ленты вниз происходит обратное действие.

Подобного рода анимация мною была также замечена в приложении Play Market. При переходе в любую категорию (например игры), при прокручивании вниз плавно скрывается `ActionBar`.

Я попытался реализовать подобную вещь с использованием `transition-анимации` и обычного вертикального `LinearLayout`, в котором много элементов. Также я использовал `OnScrollChangedListener`. Ничего не получилось.

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно реализовать подобную анимацию и если можно пример реализации!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Совсем недавно была представлена библиотека поддержки от google - `support:design` , в которую, помимо прочих нужных вещей, входит новый виджет: [`CollapsingToolbarLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog) - данный виджет реализует требующуюся вам функциональность от производителя.  Подробности использования данного виджета вы можете посмотреть [в релизе к этой библиотеки](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) , раздел **Collapsing Toolbars**.

Ранее лучше всего такой эффект был реализован в библиотеке [`ObservableScrollView`](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView) , если вы непременно задались целью реализовать этот эффект самостоятельно - изучите ее исходники, в разумных размерах это не опишешь.